# Can I use a PLAYA field as a search parameter in channel entries tag

Tags: channel-entries, playa

I would like to use a custom playa field as a search parameter in my EE channel entries tag, something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
                        channel="media_images" 
                        search:media_v_location="Denver"
                        status="open" 
                        dynamic="no"
                        disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"
                    }
```

I have the field set as searchable. I presume I should be passing in the {title} of the entry and not the {entry_id}?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually can search on playa fields if you've ticked the "Is field searchable?" for the field. I believe the title or entry id of the related field can be used in the search.

For example, both should work:

```
{!--with channel entries--}
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="your_channel" 
    search:playa_field_name="an_entry_id"
}
    {title}<br>
{/exp:channel:entries}

{!--with playa--}
{exp:playa:parents 
    channel="your_channel" 
    search:playa_field_name="a_title_keyword"
    field="playa_field_name"
}
    {title}<br>
{/exp:playa:parents}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#search-field-name only fields of the type “Text Input”, “Textarea”, and “Drop-down Lists” are searched with this parameter.

Comment: This is true, but a lot of 3rd party fields, behind their custom interfaces, represent themselves to EE as one of these field types, so it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 2):

I have written an add-on that helps filter channel entries by their Playa relationships. If the solution above doesn't quite do it for you, check out [PaternitEE on Devot:ee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/paternitee).